# Matlab: Recursive function to find sum of numbers greater than k

Tags: matlab, recursion

Hi I am using matlab and need to write a function that works out the number of numbers in a vector that are greater or equal to k. It should return 0 if there are none.

So far this is what I have done:

```
function totalnumb = numbgreater(v,k)
if any(v>=k) == 0
   totalnumb = 0
else


end
end
```

I am struggling with writing what should be written below else. I have thought of finding the indexes of numbers >= k using find(v>=k) but then I am confused as to how I could use recursion to count them. 
If someone could help would be great.
Many thanks

Comment: Why does your title have "Python"? Also, why use recursion? Matlab is very slow at it. Also, why not just `totalnumb = nnz(v>=k)` (without any of the if/else nonsense)?

Comment: @SchighSchagh It is compulsory for me to use recursion

Comment: @SchighSchagh i dont understand what does  totalnumb = nnz(v>=k) do? Would it still be doable using an if else loop

Comment: Solving this problem with recursion is really odd. However if you really need to use recursion, you could use `find(...,1)` to find the first element `>=k`. Then set this element of `v` to `k-1` and set `totalnumb` to `1+numbgreater(v,k)`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Would you be able to write it in my program so I can understand how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your problem, it's actually quite simple to write something recursive.  In this particular case, you can approach recursive programs is to figure out how this could be done with a `for` loop, then modify it so that it's recursive.  Think about how you would do this in a loop.  We would check every single number in this vector one at a time, and see if it's greater than `k`.  If it is, we increment a counter by 1.  If not, we don't increment.

As mentioned by patrik in his comment to me below, recursion is much more than this.  There are very complex algorithms that use recursion as a way of solving a problem that doesn't rely on this "loopy" structure.  For example, Depth-First Search is an graph searching algorithm that searches for nodes in a particular order.  It boils down to using a stack, and you can elegantly represent this using recursion.  This could be done in a `for` loop (`while` loop actually), but it's much more elegant to represent this in recursion.  However, for your case, start off with recursion in this way.  It'll get your feet off the ground at least.

As such, with any recursive algorithm, you need what is known as the **base** case.  The base case is when we know for sure what the output should be when given the most simplest input.  In our case, this is simply when we specify an input of length 1 or 1 element.  If we have just 1 element, then if this element is greater than `k`, we return 1 and else we return 0.

If the input **isn't** one element but a vector, then you would check to see if the first element in this vector is greater than `k`.  If it is, the result would be 1 + the recursive call on a vector where we **skip** the first element and look at the rest.  If it isn't, then we don't add one, but still look at the rest of the elements anyway.  This is what is known as the **recursive** case.

As such, your code may look something like this:

```
function totalnumb = numbgreater(v,k)
    %// Base case - if number of input elements is 1
    if numel(v) == 1
        if v > k % //Is input number > k? If it is, return 1
            totalnumb = 1;
        else % //If not, return 0
            totalnumb = 0;
        end
    else %// Recursive case
        if v(1) > k %// Is first element in this vector greater than k?
            %// if yes, then that's 1 number that's greater, so we take 1
            %// then add with calling this function again looking at the
            %// second element of this vector onwards
            totalnumb = 1 + numbgreater(v(2:end), k);
        else
            %// if no, then do the same thing as above, but don't add 1 as
            %// the condition isn't satisfied
            totalnumb = numbgreater(v(2:end), k);
        end
    end
```

So, if we declared `v` to be something like:

```
v = [2 3 4 1 5 6 2 3];
```

... and if we declared `k = 3`, if we called this function with `v` and `k`, we get:

```
totalnumb = numbgreater(v, 3)

totalnumb = 

   3
```

This makes sense.  There are only three numbers that are larger than 3.  That would be 4, 5 and 6, located at positions 3, 5 and 6 respectively.

Recursion is a tricky business to master.  Once you get the hang of it, a lot of algorithms can eloquently be solved using recursion.

Good luck!

Comment: I must say that I not fully agree about how you look at recursion. While it is definitely possible to create recursion this way, you might as well do a loop in many of these cases. However, in general I use recursion to reduce complexity. Let have a tree climb for example. The tree have a trunk emerging in branches. When you climb a tree you normally climb the first branch and then check, what is the most stable branch leading upwards and is it safe. Each step of the function is unaware of the global state, but it still does the right thing. This gives code which is easier to write and read.

Comment: @patrik - I agree.  It's a rather simplified way of looking at recursion and it's something to start with... but something like Depth-First Search can't be done elegantly in a loop and recursion is the way to go with that.  However, for this example, it works.  If you have another way of doing this recursively, I would certainly like to see it.  FWIW, I've edited my post to include this caveat.

Comment: @patrik The approach Ray is using is called **tail recursion** and is the simplest way convert a recursive algorithm to/from an iterative one. I'll post a solution that will probably look more like what you would call recursion.

Comment: @beaker - That's exactly it.  I couldn't remember what it was called, but this is the approach I used when dealing with strongly typed languages that don't support mutation (ML, Racket, Haskell, etc.).  I found considering recursion in this sense easier to understand first before moving on to more advanced algorithms that use it (DFS for example).  I'd like to see your solution too beaker! Thanks!

Comment: Done. If you could check and make sure it's all clear I'd appreciate it.

Comment: @beaker - Totally fine.  That's basically dividing and conquering.  Another great way to solve it, and it eliminates the `if/else` checks I have in the recursive case.

Comment: That's exactly what it is. (Un)Fortunately there isn't a lot of information that has to be passed to the different recursion layers like DFS where you have to keep the predecessor array, which vertices have been visited and so forth. Recursion is much more helpful there, but we knew this was a manufactured problem when we started. :)

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comments to @rayryeng's answer, his solution uses **tail recursion**. Recursion in general takes a problem, solves part of it, calls the same function again on the rest, and combines the two answers. In this case, given two parts of a vector:

```
v(1) and v(2:end)
```

we find the solution for `v(1)` and then call `numbgreater` on `v(2:end)`. This is done in the `Recursive case` portion of Ray's code. I've removed most of the comments for brevity and made one minor change to make things explicit:

```
else %// Recursive case
    if v(1) > k 
        totalnumb = 1 + numbgreater(v(2:end), k);
    else
        totalnumb = 0 + numbgreater(v(2:end), k);
    end
end
```

Now both cases have the solution for `v(1)` plus the solution for the rest.

Say, instead of finding the solution for just `v(1)`, we wanted to find the solution for the entire first half of the vector and then add that to the solution for entire second half of the vector. How would that look? Well, instead of figuring out whether to add `0` or `1`, we just split the vector in two and call `numbgreater` on both parts:

```
else
   mp=floor(numel(v)/2); %// find the midpoint
   %// Call numbgreater() on both halves and add the results
   totalnumb = numbgreater(v(1:mp),k) + numbgreater(v(mp+1:end),k);
end
```

So where do we ever calculate whether we add `1` or not? That's still handled in the `Base case` portion of the code:

```
if numel(v) == 1
    if v > k % //Is input number > k? If it is, return 1
        totalnumb = 1;
    else % //If not, return 0
        totalnumb = 0;
    end
```

So we keep dividing the vector down and calling new versions of the function until the length of each sub-vector is 1, and then add them all back together as we pop back up the recursion stack. So here's our new function:

```
function totalnumb = numbgreater(v,k)
    %// Base case - if number of input elements is 1
    if numel(v) == 1
        if v > k 
            totalnumb = 1;
        else % 
            totalnumb = 0;
        end
    else %// Recursive case
        mp=floor(numel(v)/2); %// find the midpoint
        totalnumb = numbgreater(v(1:mp),k) + numbgreater(v(mp+1:end),k);
    end
end
```

I used the following commands to generate some test data and call the function:

```
v=randi(10,1,10)
n=numbgreater(v,4)
```

The output should be something like:

```
v =

    9   10    3    2    9    8    2    2   10    7

n =  6
```

Comment: You don't need an `end` keyword if the file consists of only a `function`.  You do need it if you have multiple functions defined within the file.  However, aside from that, this a great approach very much akin to dividing and conquering, like merge sort.  Thanks for posting!